# Jenkins can't find maven setting.xml file outside Jenkins Home

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have Jenkins running on CentOS server and I'm trying to set up a job that runs **mvn clean install** on a git project. Since I want to use a global maven repository for my whole server, I'm setting up my project to run maven using a setting file in a path outside Jenkins home:

[image]

When running the build, Jenkins can't find that settings.xml file:

```
...
[workspace] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.4/bin/mvn -f firma-digital-service/pom.xml -s /home/dcalderon/.m2/repository/settings.xml -X clean package
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.4
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-123.4.2.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: The specified user settings file does not exist: /home/dcalderon/.m2/repository/settings.xml
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.settings(MavenCli.java:681)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

When running the exact same commands Jenkins runs via command line everything works correctly which show that the file does exist in the server. What am I doing wrong? Is it an issue regarding user restrictions?

Comment: Do you use the same settings.xml file when run on the console? Is the file readable by the User Jenkins is running?

Comment: 1st question: yes I specify which settings.xml file using -s parameter. 2nd question: that's what I'm not sure, how can I know which user Jenkins is running? I call sudo service start jenkins with dcalderon.

Comment: "ps -ef" ought to tell you what user is running the jenkins process. Given that you run it with sudo, I guess that it will be root. Your error message is very explicit so I would check the permissions on the .m2 folder and maybe try chmod a+x on it to see if that helps. (root can see into '700' directories in my linux user's home on Ubuntu, though, so I'm not sure this is your problem.)

Comment: Usually jenkins is not run as root. Guess this is the problem then, the User habe noch access rights to the file.

Comment: Best way to handle this in Jenkins is to use the config file provider plugin and define the appropriate settings.xml file there and use it from there and don't rely on a file which is on the file system

Answer (score 3):

As an extension answer, when there are no specific changes to configuration, we can also say to use default settings for maven in the Jenkins configuration as mentioned below:

Settings file:  Use default maven settings
Global Settings file: Use default maven global settings

[image: Maven Settings in Jenkins Job Configuration Page]

Comment: Changing Settings File and Global Settings file to default settings resolved mine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin to manage the settings.xml.

just provide the relevant file to your project using this plugin.

Thanks , Mor

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins runs as **jenkins** user so it can't see a file located in **/home/dcalderon** folder

Answer (score 0):

I am using the scripted pipeline and in my case added/updated the settings.xml file located at `/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/` folder.